# How to restrict port number selection in adventsnmp API when creation SNMP session?

Tags: api, port, snmp

I am using the Advent SNMP API to create an SNMP session, creating 50 sessions once for use in different threads. I need to restrict some port to not be occupied by an SNMP session: Let's say the sessions are created from port number 80100 to 80150, then I need to restrict port number 80130, so it is not occupied by an SNMP session.